# index must be a positive integer or logical: But it is

Tags: matlab

So, I'm attempting to access an array of length 165888. I'm looping through, calculating my index as I go. At one point, I get to 110689, and this, for some reason, throws the following error:

`Attempted to access buf(110689); index must be a positive integer or logical.`

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a rounding thing. I was doing a calculation, and forgetting to round.